# PHP mail() function not working on localhost:4000

Tags: php, email, localhost

I'm using localhost:4000 for PHP and I got error on e-mail sending:
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Users\schpe\www\contact.php on line 33

I have no php.ini file (just development and production)

PHP:

```
<?php
$errors = [];
$errorMessage = '';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if (empty($name)) {
        $errors[] = 'Name is empty';
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        $errors[] = 'Email is empty';
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] = 'Email is invalid';
    }

    if (empty($message)) {
        $errors[] = 'Message is empty';
    }


    if (empty($errors)) {
        $toEmail = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';
        $emailSubject = 'New email from your contant form';
        $headers = ['From' => $email, 'Reply-To' => $email, 'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'];

        $bodyParagraphs = ["Name: {$name}", "Email: {$email}", "Message:", $message];
        $body = join(PHP_EOL, $bodyParagraphs);

        if (mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $body, $headers)) {
            header('Location: index.html');
        } else {
            $errorMessage = 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again later';
        }
    } else {
        $allErrors = join('<br/>', $errors);
        $errorMessage = "<p style='color: red;'>{$allErrors}</p>";
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: On Windows? Are you running a stack like xampp or wamp?  Do you have a mail server installed on localhost machine?

Comment: Yes on windows, no I'm not using a stack and have not installed a mail server

Comment: Ok, and are you planning on installing a local mail server or using an external service like gmail or similar? If you are running php you will have a php.ini however. Once you have decided what mail server you are going to use, you would then need to configure it in php.ini. I see some html output in your code. Is this a for a website? If so what server are you using - iis, nginx, apache,.. ?